# Google Map API Zoom plus and minus Icon not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Its the web application page. I am able to show the google map, but Zoom + & - icons not showing. But i am able to control the zoom.

I checked in various way.
1, Image is not downloaded from the google map api.
2, They called in script(control.js) to download the image and alsp its not appending into the html.
3, i am getting like this , but it should be   .

[image]

And in control.js they wrote the code to append the img into button. Its appending but with src null. Below the code for your reference.

```
 wK = function(a, b, c, d) {
        a.innerText = "";
        b = _.ua(0 == b ? 1 == c ? ['<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">\n  <polygon fill="#666" points="18,7 11,7 11,0 7,0 7,7 0,7 0,11 7,11 7,18 11,18 11,11 18,11"/>\n</svg>\n', '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">\n  <polygon fill="#B1B1B1" points="18,7 11,7 11,0 7,0 7,7 0,7 0,11 7,11 7,18 11,18 11,11 18,11"/>\n</svg>\n', '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">\n  <polygon fill="#E4E4E4" points="18,7 11,7 11,0 7,0 7,7 0,7 0,11 7,11 7,18 11,18 11,11 18,11"/>\n</svg>\n'] : ['<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">\n  <polygon fill="#666" points="18,7 11,7 11,0 7,0 7,7 0,7 0,11 7,11 7,18 11,18 11,11 18,11"/>\n</svg>\n', '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">\n  <polygon fill="#333" points="18,7 11,7 11,0 7,0 7,7 0,7 0,11 7,11 7,18 11,18 11,11 18,11"/>\n</svg>\n', '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">\n  <polygon fill="#111" points="18,7 11,7 11,0 7,0 7,7 0,7 0,11 7,11 7,18 11,18 11,11 18,11"/>\n</svg>\n'] : 1 == c ? ['<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">\n  <path fill="#666" d="M0,7h18v4H0V7z"/>\n</svg>\n', '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">\n  <path fill="#B1B1B1" d="M0,7h18v4H0V7z"/>\n</svg>\n', '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">\n  <path fill="#E4E4E4" d="M0,7h18v4H0V7z"/>\n</svg>\n'] : ['<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">\n  <path fill="#666" d="M0,7h18v4H0V7z"/>\n</svg>\n', '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">\n  <path fill="#333" d="M0,7h18v4H0V7z"/>\n</svg>\n', '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18">\n  <path fill="#111" d="M0,7h18v4H0V7z"/>\n</svg>\n']);
        for (c = b.next(); !c.done; c = b.next()) {
            c = c.value;
            var e = document.createElement("img");
            e.style.width = e.style.height = _.W(ZI(d));
            e.src = _.$A(c);
            a.appendChild(e)
        }
    }
```

Note: I am not getting any error on my console regarding Google map. Version : 3.36

Answer (score 0):

Are you currently using google maps api?

did you add to the class with your component

`/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />`

an alternative i can give you is to try Angular Google Maps (AGM):
https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/

hope this can help you

Comment: Yes i am using Google maps API. But, here i am not implemented with angular, so that am not using AGM Phoenix.

Comment: have you tri adding  `/// <reference types="@types/googlemaps" />` in the component implementing the map?